# Debian/LXDE terminal, how to disable it/disable the panel bar

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I m on Raspberry pi running Raspbian.
The standart terminal is LXDE

I m fine with it, but the panel bar pop up upon the video I m playing.

Is there a way to disable it, it would be perfect if it can also be restarted after the video stop running (from a script).

The only answer I found is to use

```
pkill -9 lxpanel
```

But I also found that kill -9 is highly unreccomanded, also is p command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the panel to auto hide.

Right click on the panel, and you'll get this menu.

[image: panel menu]

Select `Panel Settings` and you'll get this dialog.

[image: panel preferences]

Select `Minimise panel when not in use`

Comment: It does work, I just discovered that the LXDE panel bar wasn t the only one to pop up. I ll get around it by starting the script at boot, before LXDE start.

Answer (score 15):

Edit the configuration file of the panel :

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel
```

At the very top of the file, in the General section, you can modify these parameters

```
autohide=0
heightwhenhidden=2
```

You can replace them by

```
autohide=1
heightwhenhidden=0
```

if you want it to completely disappear